# Why is my UITableView not showing?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I can't figure out why my TableView is not showing. Its probably something stupid but all of my MenuItemStruct's are complete and not null and my table view seems set up correctly to me. There are no errors, but my cellForRowAt method is not getting called. Please help?

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var menuNavigationDelegate: MenuNavigationDelegate?, menuManagerDelegate: MenuManagerDelegate?
    var conferenceId = "conferenceId-1"

    var isDataLoading = false


    @IBOutlet
    var menuTableView: UITableView?

    var menuItems = Array<MenuItemStruct>()

    @IBAction
    func closeMenuTapped() {
        self.menuManagerDelegate?.closeMenu()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.menuTableView?.register(UINib(nibName: "MenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "menuCell")
        self.isDataLoading = true
        MenuDataManager.getMenuInformation(conferenceId: self.conferenceId) {
            menuItems, response, error in
            self.menuItems = menuItems!
            self.isDataLoading = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.menuTableView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
        self.menuTableView?.reloadData()
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MenuTableViewCell = menuTableView!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
        if (!self.isDataLoading) {
            cell.setUpCellWithData(menuItem: menuItems[indexPath.row])
        }

        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(!self.isDataLoading) {
            return self.menuItems.count
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check if you have connected the datasource and delegate of the tableview. Your outlet reference for the tableView should be like     @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView! and make sure its connected as well.

Comment: You forgot to set the tableViews Delegate & DataSource

Comment: Please check if your `numberOfRowsInSection` is called. If it isn't, the dataSource and delegate has not been set for the `UITableView`. If it is being called, your `numberOfRowsInSection` must be always returning 0.

Comment: you guys are definitely right. I was not hooking up my datasource and delegate correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the delegate and datasource of your table view. You have included the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols, but have not assigned a delegate and datasource for your tableview in the code.

Try something like this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.menuTableView.delegate = self
self.menuTableView.dataSource = self
```